# Getting error while trying to generate the signed apk from android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I am getting the following code whenever I try to generate signed APK of my app

```
Error: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\32.0.0\zipalign.exe -f 4 C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\android6.apk C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\project\1.5.3\Apps\Customer\Customer.apk
Unable to open 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\android6.apk' as zip archive
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is showing that you opening your app direct with .zip file.
First, Unzip (extract) your App using WinRar, 7zip etc and then Open it using Android Studio. If you are still getting error then let me know with screenshot.

Comment: thank you but that did not solve it. i am still getting the exact error